# Hiding file in the directory from non-root users

Tags: ubuntu

So I use KeePassx to store my passwords and I have a key file. I know I can just encrypt that file, but is it possible to store that key file somewhere on the system hidden and protected from non-root users?

Let's say I enter root password, file appears in some directory, I use it to open my KeyPassx database and then I hide that file once again.

For example I `chmod 700 secretFolder` which contains the key, but I still can display file and its contents without entering `sudo`. I want the file to appear in the directory only when I enter root password.

Comment: This is a unix question, not an ubuntu question. It might be better suited to unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: chown the file to root.  A 700 lets the owner have access to the file also.  If a DIFFERNT user tried to read the file with 700 they wouldn't be able to, only the owner and root.  If you want only root then root needs to own the file.

Comment: Ok,`chown root secretFolder` works :) But are there any security implications with starting KeePassx with gksudo each time?